# UDT Unsupported Token Issue when using System.Data.SqlClient on CoreFx

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core

I have created a basic .Net Core Console test app to connect to a local Sql Server instance and retrieve data.  The same code works fine when targeting the .Net 4.6.1 but not when targeting .Net Core:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SqlServerTests
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder statement = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM calendars as i WHERE i.Id='[id]");

                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("[Connection works fine]");

                sqlConnection.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(statement.ToString(), sqlConnection);
                SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (!sqlReader.HasRows)
                    Console.WriteLine("No data found"); ;

                List<dynamic> dataSet = new List<dynamic>();

                if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        dynamic dataObject = new ExpandoObject();
                        var data = dataObject as IDictionary<string, object>;

                        for (int i = 0; i < sqlReader.FieldCount; i++)
                            data[sqlReader.GetName(i)] = !sqlReader.IsDBNull(i) ? sqlReader.GetValue(i) : null;

                        dataSet.Add(data);
                    }

                Console.WriteLine(dataSet.FirstOrDefault());

                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                //Exception code omitted
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The connection works (another app uses the same connection to save data), and when running Sql Server Profiler the query executes as expected (data is also retrieved as expected when pasting the query onto Sql Server Management Studio), but when calling ExecuteReader on the Console app I receive the following message:

> The server is attempting to use a feature that is not
>   supported on this platform. Received an unsupported token 'Udt' while
>   reading data from the server.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryCommonProcessMetaData(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, _SqlMetaData col)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryProcessMetaData(Int32 cColumns,
>   TdsParserStateObject stateObj, _SqlMetaDataSet& metaData)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()    at
>   SqlServerTests.Program.Main(String[] args) in...

I am assuming that I have missed something when using this code in a .Net Core app, but I just can't find what.

Comment: Hi Salty, Thank you for your reply, you were right about the UDT.  The table had a geography data type as a column, and based on your suggestion I selected this by converting it to a varchar (CONVERT(varchar(100), [Location]), and the query results load as expected.

Comment: I also stuck in same problem. Could you please elaborate your answer a bit or may be code snippet.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the SqlClient source code, it would appear that UDTs are still very much unsupported. In my situation I'm trying to insert a record which includes a HierarchyId column. I receive 'The server is attempting to use a feature that is not supported on this platform.' from the TdsParser.

The class is (currently) here:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs

If you search for SQLUDT you'll find entries similar to the following:

```
case TdsEnums.SQLUDT:
    throw SQL.UnsupportedFeatureAndToken(_connHandler, SqlDbType.Udt.ToString());
```

This is as of MyGet Package: System.Data.SqlClient 4.1.1-beta-24222-02

**Update:** I was able to get a simple insert statement to work through Dapper by sending the HierarchyId in string representation. SqlBulkCopy is still a no-go at this stage. From a read perspective, I receive the unsupported exception if I reference the HierarchyId column in the SELECT statement. However using SQL Convert `CONVERT(varchar(8000), [HierarchyColumn])` in the SQL Query successfully returns the string representation at least.

It makes some sense, its not like we have access to the existing UDT classes like SqlHierarchyId.

If you change the original `StringBuilder statement = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM calendars as i WHERE i.Id='[id]");` so that the SELECT statement references the columns explicitly and also perform a conversion on your UDT columns you should get something more useful back.